# Verifying multiple Apple Pay merchants on the same domain

Tags: applepay

We already have a `/.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association.txt` file under our domain which is used to verify our domain to Apple in relation to a checkout.com Apple Pay integration. Now we wish to have a completely independent Apple Pay integration (i.e. a different Apple merchant) using Adyen, operating under the same domain. This means we need to verify that too, by hosting a different `/.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association.txt`... how can this be done while making sure the existing checkout.com integration doesn't lose its verification?

I was hoping maybe Apple includes some kind of header in the request signifying which merchant ID it's verifying, and based off of that we could dynamically change what we present? But I couldn't find anywhere detailing the exact process that goes on.

I've found lots of threads on the Apple developer forums about this, but none with a conclusive answer:

- https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/718160
- https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/118725
- https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/695538

Only the last one provides any kind of answer, which doesn't feel particularly robust as it seems like a big assumption that once it's verified Apple will *never* check again, an assumption that doesn't seem to be documented anywhere?

Are there any other possible solutions here?